# ng2 send formgroup to component as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I Have FormGroup contains Sub FormGroup:

```
sub formGroup initalize:
    this.fg=new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(),
        abcFg: new FormGroup({
            aaa: new FormControl(),
            bbb: new FormControl()
        })
    });
```

I have main component contains abcComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'mainComponent',
    styles: [],
    providers: [],
    template: `
         <div *ngIf="fg">
             <form [formGroup]="fg">
                  <abcComponent></abcComponent>
             </form>
         </div>
         `
```

**I want to send sub formGroup (abc) to abcComponent as parameter(input).**

abcComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'abcComponent',
    styles: [],
    providers: [],
    template: `
         <div *ngIf="abcFg">
             <form [formGroup]="abcFg">
                 <input type="text" formControlName="aaa" />
                 <input type="text" formControlName="bbb" />
             </form>
         </div>
         `
export class AbcComponent{ 
    @input() public abcFg:FormGroup;
}
```

I tried this:

```
<abcComponent [abcFg]="fg.controls[abcFg"]"></abcComponent>
```

But its not working... How can i fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: `<abcComponent [abcFg]="fg.get('abcFg')"></abcComponent>` ?

Comment: abcComponent has input parameter names 'abcFg'. i tried to send the sub formGroup to the input parameter.
this row belong to mainComponent instead of 
<abcComponent></abcComponent>

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: I guess you need just to create own custom control component, like [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: yurzui - sorry... i did not understand you before.... 
your code also not working... :(

Comment: Hmm... It works well for me https://plnkr.co/edit/vqdIw6WgrGET9BWKDHx1?p=preview

Comment: You are right! i had a mistake in other place.... its work well and i like this solution becuase in your solution i don't have to write the form controls names twice... Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass value of `abcFg` to your `abcComponent` like this:

```
<abcComponent [abcFg]="fg.value.abcFg"></abcComponent>
```

then in your `abcComponent`:

```
export class AbcComponent implements OnInit{ 
    @input() public abcFg;
    abcfgForm : FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.abcfgForm = this.fb.group({
            aaa: [this.abcFg.aaa],
            bbb: [this.abcFg.bbb]
        });
    }
}
```